# input type=file not working in iOS

Tags: javascript, iphone, cordova

I am developing application for iOS using phonegap.I want to upload my local files like image, songs, videos present on the device to the server. For this I have used `<input type="file">` for the browsing the file hierarchy . Its working fine on the browser but when I am running this on iPad **choose File** button getting disabled.I have googled lot for this problem but not able to find an appropriate solution.Does  above tag support in iOS ? if not then what is the solution to browse and upload the file in iOS?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Arbitrary file upload is not supported on iOS. The tag used to be ignored up to (and including) iOS 5.x.

Starting with iOS 6, this tag allows the user to add a photo from the photo stream or the camera ("take new photo"). All of this will be handled behind the scenes by the browser and the user will never see a real low-level "choose file" dialog.

Comment: if i am using iOS 5 then what is the solution for this problem ?

Comment: There is none. Apple decided to disallow this in the browser.

Comment: @V-Xtreme: Do you really think Apple guys "forgot" to add a filesystem and "forgot" to add a way to manage file upload/download? Those are deliberate decisions... they just don't want you to be able to do that.

Comment: Then nothing can be done to upload file from local iOS device ? One thing if i use button there instead of <input type="file"> .Then on button click can I browse through the files using javascript. same as UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary in objective c.

Comment: @V-Xtreme Have you ever seen a *file browser dialog* on iOS? In *any* app? How do you even define "file" in iOS?

Comment: @6502:agreed.Forget about upload part .Atleast can i browse through the file system of device  using javascript? same as UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary for open photo library of device.

Comment: Note that any file choosen (uploaded) via iOS 6+ will always have the useless name "`image.<ext>`". (See [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21135037/1078886)).