# HTML Upload on iPhone (iOS): filename is always same (image.jpg, image.png, ...)

Tags: html, ios, iphone, post, file-upload

I am using very simple code to upload files in my responsive website. But when I upload image using `iPhone`, the image name is always `image.jpg` irrespective of actual image name.

Any workaround for this problem?

I created this sample page with small code for debugging purpose:

```
<?php

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
    {
        print "<pre>";
        echo 'post object info:';
        print_r($_FILES);
        print "</pre>";
    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>File Upload Test for iphone</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="512000" />
        <input name="userfile" type="file" /> <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Send File" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/VnTfb3/55dev?

Comment: It could be an Apple restriction for some security reason. You could use the javascript FILE API and try to retrieve the image name you want to upload . Try to see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15876584/mobile-safari-image-upload-their-sizes

Comment: I noticed this issue is fixed in iOS10 Safari, which is good.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem but I was using 3 images in my upload script.  The quickest, easiest solution for me was to add the current date and time in any format (epoch is probably the best for this) as well as a letter or combination of letters to the filename to distinguish the filename.

```
$date = date('U');

$filename1 = str_replace(' ', '%20', $_FILES['image1']['name']);

$target1 = 'images/';

$file1 = $_FILES['image1'];

$target1 .= $date.'A'.$file1['name'];

$fileName1 = $date.'A'.$file1['name'];
```

The above is some of the code I used for my script but my script is obviously much different than yours.  I just pasted it to show how you can modify the name of a file when it is being processed and uploaded.